# Change label text based on textfield

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel, ibaction

I'm making a little demo app and I'm having trouble changing.
Heres the thing:
I have a UIButton that every click will add a character in a NSString in a UITextField. 
And I put an IBAction(Mudar_Resposta)  on that UITextField(campo) in the part 'Value Changed'. 
In that IBAction, I put that:

```
- (IBAction)MudarResposta:(id)sender {
   campo.text=@"lol";
}
```

But I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to get it to work is to connect an action method to the `Touch Up Inside` event for your button. Within that method, edit they text for your text field.

```
- (IBAction)mudarResponsta:(id)sender {    // Connect to Touch Up Inside of your button
    campo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:%@ %@", campo.text, @"lol"];    // Add string ' lol' every time it's called
}
```

Connecting to `Value Changed` will never invoke the method because the value is never being changed—you're connecting the changing method to the change…if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you didn't connect that action to anything in the XIB file.

Comment: Yes, it's linked to the 'Value Changed' of the UITextField. Checked a dozen times.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {
[self.contacts addObject:_txtField.text];
_txtField.text=@"";

}
```

Here contacts is an Array name which is a Mutable Array. txtField is UITextField.

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: @jmattheis got it?

Comment: You could also add, what the op's mistake was and why you'r code should fix this.